# Angular Material Radio Button Label is ugly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I don't know why it actually looks so ugly and so different from the examples that are given by Angular Material.
[image]

The label is not on the same height as the buttons and the font size seems to differ.

I've also tried to use a `mat-label` now but it does not change anything.

HTML:

```
  <form [formGroup]="audioConfig" style="text-align: center;">
    <mat-label>{{ "APPLICATIONS.FACE_DETECTION.BUTTONS.LANGUAGE" | translate }}</mat-label> 
    <mat-radio-group formControlName="radioButtonLanguage"
      class="example-radio-group">
      <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" [checked]="true" value="german">{{ "APPLICATIONS.FACE_DETECTION.BUTTONS.LANGUAGES.GERMAN" | translate }}
      </mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" value="english">{{ "APPLICATIONS.FACE_DETECTION.BUTTONS.LANGUAGES.ENGLISH" | translate }}
      </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
  </form>
```

In the examples, they are doing nothing different but still, it looks completely different (https://material.angular.io/components/radio/examples).

Comment: Are you using a different font?

Comment: Nope. Everything standard @BojanKogoj

Comment: You can check in developer tools what css rules are applied to labels

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `<mat-label>` in `<span>` like so

`<span><mat-label>{{ "APPLICATIONS.FACE_DETECTION.BUTTONS.LANGUAGE" | translate }}</mat-label></span>`

apply CSS Styles to your `<form>`
`display: flex; align-items: center;`

Also, you can provide the default checked value in FormControl initialization instead of HTML property `[checked]=true`

e.g.

```
fb: FormBuilder = new FormBuilder();
audioConfig: FormGroup = this.initAudioConfigFg();

initAudioConfigFg(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({ radioButtonLanguage: this.fb.control('german') });
}
```